# How to set a ToolTip for each ListBoxItem

Tags: wpf, listbox, tooltip, itemtemplate

I have a `ListBox` control; how would I set the `ToolTip` for each `ListBoxItem` using the code below.

```
<ListBox Name="FillSelections" 
         VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
         Margin="1, 3, 1, 3"
         IsEnabled="True" 
         Grid.Column="0" 
         Background="Transparent"
         HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
         SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedColor}"
         SelectionMode="Single"
         Style="{StaticResource HorizontalListBoxStyle}"
         ItemsSource="{Binding FillColors}"
         ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ColorsItemTemplate}">
</ListBox>

<DataTemplate x:Key="ColorsItemTemplate">
    <Border Width="20" 
            Height="16"
            BorderBrush="Black"
            BorderThickness="1">
        <Border.Background>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding}" />
        </Border.Background>
        <Path Stroke="Red" 
              StrokeThickness="3"
              x:Name="abc"
              Visibility="Hidden">
            <Path.Data>
                <LineGeometry StartPoint="0,16" EndPoint="20,0"/>
            </Path.Data>
        </Path>
    </Border>
    <DataTemplate.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding}" Value="#00FFFFFF">
            <Setter TargetName="abc" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </DataTemplate.Triggers>
</DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a style for `ListBoxItem`. So something along the lines of:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication3.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="ToolTip">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ToolTip>
                        <TextBlock>Hello</TextBlock>
                    </ToolTip>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
   </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <ListBox>
            <ListBoxItem>
                <TextBlock Text="Hello" />
            </ListBoxItem>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: I did try but only thing is I cant change my datatemplate and it has to be outside from my listbox control, see image of my listbox control - http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/b65c159c-2400-44f1-8a95-2a167cd5b3a1 - TOOLTIP FOR EACH ITEM IN LIST BOX

Comment: I don't get it. You wouldn't be changing your datatemplate if you add a style. You can put it wherever you want, put it in `<Window.Resources>` instead of in `<ListBox.Resources>`.

Answer (score 6):

Try something like this

```
<ListBox Width="400" Margin="10" 
         ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource myTodoList}}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=TaskName}" 
                       ToolTipService.ToolTip="{Binding Path=TheTooltipText}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
     </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Of course adapt the ItemsSource binding with whatever your binding source is, and the binding Path parts with whatever public property of the objects in the list you actually want to display.

Comment: I did try but only thing is I cant change my datatemplate and it has to be outside from my listbox control, see image of my listbox control - http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/b65c159c-2400-44f1-8a95-2a167cd5b3a1 - TOOLTIP FOR EACH ITEM IN LIST BOX

Comment: This stops the Keyboard naviagation as well ... you can't hit B to jump down to the "B"s